# Makefile:252: recipe for target 'install' failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

I'm trying to install pwlib on my asterisk/ubuntu 16.04 Server, but when I try to run `make install` I get the following error message:

```
( for dir in /usr/local/lib \
             /usr/local/bin \
             /usr/local/include/ptlib \
                     /usr/local/include/ptlib/unix/ptlib \
                     /usr/local/include/ptclib \
                     /usr/local/share/pwlib/make ; \
        do mkdir -p $dir ; chmod 755 $dir ; \
done )
/usr/bin/install -c -m 444 lib/libpt_linux_x86_64_r.so.1.12.0 /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'lib/libpt_linux_x86_64_r.so.1.12.0': No such file or directory
Makefile:252: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Greetings

Alessio

Comment: What's wrong with the ptlib from the Ubuntu package manager?

Answer (score 9):

Aware this is an old post but for anyone with a similar issue:

Sometimes running

```
make install
```

will throw this error while

```
sudo make install
```

will work

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**
This does not seem to be a makefile error, like your tags suggest.
Instead, the error lies in [install](https://linux.die.net/man/1/install). I'm not sure what the `-c` option does, since the man page only says `(ignored)`, but with `-m` you are trying to set [permissions](https://linuxhandbook.com/linux-file-permissions/) to a file. `lib/libpt_linux_x86_64_r.so.1.12.0` located in `/usr/local/lib`. However, this file does not exist in this location, as indicated by the error message `No such file or directory`.

I guess that you forgot to install some dependencies.

**Solutions**

- If you have a [configure](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-magic-behind-configure-make-make-install) script in your downloaded files, use it, maybe this will solve your dependency issues.
- If this does not work, try installing your dependencies manually
- You could also try alternatives, like the [ptlib](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/ptlib.html) library, which is also available as package. For ubuntu, it should be [libpth20](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libpth20), but I don't use ubuntu so you might have a look around if this is the correct package for you

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

> Makefile:1264: recipe for target 'install' failed
> make: *** [install] Error 1

I scrolled through the installation locating the error message and found this:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'

I googled how to download zlib and after installing zlib I was able to complete the installation

using : `sudo make install`